# Performance of Asterisk Telephony System on Linux

Tags: performance, asterisk

I needed some idea on the max concurrent calls a standard Asterisk Telephony System can handle on a 64 bit Linux server of 4GB RAM, 4 CPU cores and 10K RPM RAID0 HDD? Most of my calls will be reads.

Any pointers in this regard will be very helpful.

Comment: Are you sure you want RAID 0?  I'd probably bung in a few more disks and have RAID10

Comment: Although it might be better to do RAID1'd system disks, and have a big RAID0 for other stuffs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That server will be a killer for Asterisk, you can expect over 5k+ concurrent calls without degradation, although on this scenario if you use some advanced codec (G729 for example) the CPU will be your limit.

Have a look at this very good document about Asterisk dimensioning, lots of very useful info there http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+dimensioning

Also Transnexus have a very good paper on CPU vs memory performance for concurrent calls http://www.transnexus.com/White%20Papers/asterisk_V1-4-11_performance.htm

Comment: I assume lynxman means when dealing with voip streams. Terminating POTS/ISDN on the same device will have a variable impact on capacity depending on the hardware used.

Comment: Yes indeed, I'm assuming SIP by default since he didn't specify any additional hardware used on his setup :)

Comment: Can we assume 2000~2500 Concurrent calls to be safe on such a setup with ISDN?

Comment: If your ISDN hardware doesn't require kernel module acceleration (those for example would be the USB ones you see lately on the market) then definitely it'll handle the traffic, just make sure your hardware is one of the recommended ones in the isdn4linux project (http://www.isdn4linux.de/)

Comment: Glad to be of any help :)

Answer (score 0):

We are having a same setup,but with 6GB of RAM. Which is connected to a PRI line. The box is handling almost 4000 call per day including human attending and IVR