# When to limit concurrent calls on Asterisk Server?

Tags: asterisk

I'm interested in building an android app that calls another android app via the Asterisk server.  It will be strictly SIP to SIP without connection to a PSTN.

I've read you can have thousands of concurrent calls based on the set up of this OP here:
[Performance of Asterisk Telephony System on Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/229073/performance-of-asterisk-telephony-system-on-linux)

So my next question is, I heard briefly that some systems administrators like to impose a limit on the number of concurrent calls.  Is the advantage here mainly to control the bandwidth and resources used on the computer?  Or are there other considerations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual reasons I can think of to limit concurrent calls would be:

- Limited bandwidth available.  Better to have 100 good quality calls than 200 horrible ones
- Possibly slow down or prevent DOS attacks from opening too many calls and bringing the server to its knees.
- Limited processing power - if the calls require reencoding for different codexs at each end it can eat a lot of cpu cycles per call